# Как добавить программу в автозапуск?

Tags: c#, windows

Написал небольшую утилиту для закрытия ненужных процессов винды при старте (Sirena, Очередь печати и тд)

Консольное приложение.

Как добавить в автозапуск?

Пробовал данный метод, но работает он криво(иногда не запускает вообще, и даже не отображается в списке Autoruns)

```
RegistryKey reg;
reg= Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
```

Comment: *Как добавить в автозапуск?* Какой именно? их много разных... Если при входе пользователя в систему - лучше создать задание в планировщике.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можешь создать ярлык на свою программу в папке авторана.

   ```
   %категория пользователя%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
   ```

Это самый "простой" способ.

Для удаления из автозапуска - просто удалить ярлык.

---

2. Можешь добавить в

   ```
   // Путь к ключу где винда смотрит настройки автозапуска
   RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

   if (!IsStartupItem())
       // Добавить значение в реестр для запуска напару с ОС
       rkApp.SetValue("My app's name", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
   ```

И программа запустится после перезапуска компьютера

Для удаления из автозапуска:

```
// Путь к ключу где винда смотрит настройки автозапуска
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

if(IsStartupItem())
    // Удаляем
    rkApp.DeleteValue("My app's name", false);
```

---

3. А можно еще добавить через планировщик заданий по какому-то специфическому триггеру известному лишь одному тебе :)

Comment: Ну-у-у... При перезагрузке, срабатывает но как-то кривовато (окно не открывается с процессом), а при завершении работы вообще не срабатывает, щас чекнул в авторанусе - его нету.

Comment: rkApp.SetValue("WindowsNetworkService", Application.ExecutablePath); Ошибка CS0103 Имя "Application" не существует в текущем контексте.